# Getting error with ng-if in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `ng-if` tag in my app, but it seems like when I load the page, it throws an error.

Here is how my code looks like

```
<ons-col width="95px">
              <img src="{{PostDetail.attachments[0].images.square1.url}}" class="thumbnail" ng-if="PostDetail.attachments[0].url != null">
              <img src="images/location1.png" class="thumbnail" ng-if="PostDetail.attachments[0].url == null">
</ons-col>
```

When a page loads or when I reload it shows this below error:

> GET
>   file://localhost/Volumes/Work%20Data/Development/Come%20to%20woodstock%20Ic…o%20Woodstock/www/%7B%7BPostDetail.attachments[0].images.square1.url%7D%7D
>   net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Is there any problem in the `ng-if`? It looks good while it works on browser, but when I load the console in my google chrome, I can see some of these above mentioned weird errors. Any solutions?

Comment: Accessing localhost over a file:// url?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid a browser eagerly retrieving the image from a not-yet-interpolated URL, e.g. `src="{{some.url}}"` (thus resulting in HTTP error), you should use `ng-src`:

```
<img ng-src="{{PostDetail.attachments[0].images.square1.url}}">
```

As for your `ng-if`, it seems to guard against a null `PostDetail.attachments[0].url` - are you sure you didn't mean `PostDetail.attachments[0].images.square1.url`?

Comment: Awesome it worked great...i was making some silly mistake here. i just realized. Can you please help me with ons-navigator problem too?

Comment: @user3201500, what is the problem with `ons-navigator`? But you should probably ask a separate question

Comment: Yes i asked a seperate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861875/ons-navigator-multiple-navigator-in-one-page-template here is the question

Comment: @user3201500, I'll take a look, although I'm not familiar with onsen.

Comment: I just asked it. So stackoverflow wants me to wait for 6 more min to accept your answer.